# What is the difference complementing with prepositional phrase and with to-infinitive?

Tags: complements

> To-infinitive complements must be distinguished from PP complement
>   with the preposition to. The following quotation illustrates the
>   difference.
>
> The global threat **to our security** was clear.
>  So was our duty
>   **to act to eliminate it**.
>  (Angela Downing, English Grammar):
>   PP: prepositional phrase

I don’t get what is the difference between complementing a noun with to-prepositional phrase and to-infinitive. Would you show me the difference?

Comment: Good question for [ell.se].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The noun *threat* may take either a prepositional phrase (PP) headed by *to* or a verb phrase (VP) headed by a marked infinitive as a complement—or both:

> ... the global threat [<sub>PP</sub> to our security]
>   ... Britain's threat [<sub>PP</sub> to France] [<sub>VP</sub> to stifle its trade]

The PP names the recipient of the threat: the person or entity against whom Britain directs the threat. The VP names the action which Britain says it will perform.

So may the noun *duty*:

> ... our duty [<sub>VP</sub> to act]
>   ... our duty [<sub>PP</sub> to our society] [<sub>VP</sub> to pay taxes]

The PP names the person to whom the duty is owed, or who imposes the obligation. The VP names the action which we are obliged to perform.

Note, however, that in your second example the **second** marked infinitive, *to eliminate it*, is an infinitive of purpose naming the purpose which our ‘acting’ is intended to achieve; it is not a complement of *duty*, but a constituent of the VP headed by the verb *act*:

> ... our duty **[<sub>VP</sub>** [<sub>VP</sub> to act] [<sub>VP</sub> to eliminate it] **]**

How you parse *to eliminate it* is ambiguous. Some might regard it as a complement of *act*, others as an adverbial adjunct modifying *act*.