# Why "to" isn't an infinitive indicator in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

> The late Mr Lee Kuan Yew has been hailed by many as "Singapore's Chief Gardener" for his vision and single-minded commitment ***to transforming*** our country into a lush garden city and creating the best possible living environment for all citizens to enjoy.

I have tried referring to these links but to no avail:

- [When is "to" a preposition and when the infinitive marker?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/103529/when-is-to-a-preposition-and-when-the-infinitive-marker) 
   This link only explains about ***want*** to see you which is helpful, and the *"look forward to seeing you"* is common on Internet. But both explanations are specific to the said grammatical instances only, not general.
- ["To hear" or "to hearing"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18772/to-hear-or-to-hearing) 
   This link only explains about *look forward to hearing*, which is again specific and special grammatical instance.
- [How to know if I should use verb+ing after the word 'to'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/253266/how-to-know-if-i-should-use-verbing-after-the-word-to?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment552932_253266) 
   This link mentions *transitivising particle*, but without elaboration and lacks citation.

No matter how much I try to use inductive reasoning, I can't figure out why using ***"...to transform our country..."*** is wrong.

Comment: Your final question is (a) totally different and (b) founded on a wrong premise.  Both 'transforming' and 'transform' are acceptable here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth elaborate please.

Comment: Your title question is about why the  “to” appearing in the sentence  "The late Mr Lee Kuan Yew has been hailed by many as _Singapore's Chief Gardener_ for his vision and single-minded commitment to transforming our country ..." isn't the infinitive indicator/marker. That's answered at the duplicate. Your final question asks why the alternative phrasing "The late Mr Lee Kuan Yew has been hailed by many as _Singapore's Chief Gardener_ for his vision and single-minded commitment to transform our country ..." isn't acceptable. But it is. See the second link I give under Madeline's answer.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I see. I wasn’t aware of the difference. I thought if _”to” is an infinitive indicator,_ it would mean ***”to transform”*** is correct. That’s why I phrased my title that way, and ends this thread with an elaboration of my original qs: *to **transform** or **transformation**?*

Comment: @XPMai I disagree with Edwin's comment here. "*hailed by many as Singapore's Chief Gardener for his vision and single-minded commitment to transform our country*" is, in my view, NOT completely felicitious. ...

Comment: @Araucaria https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78097/discussion-on-question-why-to-isnt-an-infinitive-indicator-in-this-sentence

Comment: @XPMai It's wonky because *a commitment to XYZinfinitive* means something like *a promise to XYZinfinitive*. And "*The late Mr Lee Kuan Yew has been hailed by many as Singapore's Chief Gardener for his vision and single-minded promise to transform our country ....*" doesn't work. In contrast *commitment to XYZing* means something like *devotion to the cause of XYZing*, and is compatible with *vision* and with the adjective *single-minded*.

Comment: @Araucaria Do you have a problem with 'He was praised for his vision and [for] his freely-offered promise to transform our country'? 'Commitment', like 'promise' and 'plan' etc, can take a to-infinitive complement. 'This is a significant first step towards meeting the government's commitment to increase NHS spending by a minimum of £8 billion in real terms'. {[www.gov.uk/government publications/autumn budget 2017](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/autumn-budget-2017-documents/autumn-budget-2017)} //// Ah, I've now looked at your later comment. I'll leave this as an overview though.

Answer (score 0):

"To transform our country" is wrong because of the word "commitment".

If you think of the verb "to commit *to* something/doing something", the *to* is **not** an indiciator of the infinitive but rather a **preposition** pointing to the *commitment*. Therefore, we use the gerung (ING) after a preposition.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hello, Madeline. Please add research to substantiate answers (though in this case, it won't). Both bare infinitives and ing-forms may be used after the string 'a commitment to', though there may be some  restrictions on where the infinitive may idiomatically be used. An example from [Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/commitment): 'The government gave a commitment to withdraw all its forces.' See also the correct answer (by e2efour) at the relevant  [Wordreference.com](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/commitment-to-ing.1706971/) discussion.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth This has been closed as a duplicate of other to-infinitive versus gerund participlal questions, but the answer to this question relates to the meaning of the word *commitment*. The adjective *single-minded* here more or less rules out *to-infinitive*. I think the question is worth reopening, as it would enable future readers to find that info that they are unlikely to find easily anywhere else!

Comment: @Araucaria I've found (among the claimed 114 000 000 tokens for "commitment to improve" on Google) six different attributive adjectives in the first seven pages of results, and one determiner ("_that_ commitment to improve"). This **question** doesn't address the  'commitment + to-infinitive' structure, but if it did, it would be a duplicate of [What is the difference between complementing a noun with prepositional phrase and with to-infinitive?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/113006/what-is-the-difference-complementing-with-prepositional-phrase-and-with-to-infin)....

Comment: This was IMO wrongly closed, but there are other threads discussing to-infinitival noun complements.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The point is not so much that there's an attributive adjective, it's more the meaning of *single-minded*. Where *commitment* refers to a public promise, it must take an infinitive (the commitment here is an event, so to speak). Where *commitment* means something like  *dedication* and signifies a state, not an event, it is followed by a gerund participle. That's more what I was angling at. The *single-minded* adjective, of course, works better with the latter meaning (it implies duration, compatible with a state but not a punctive event).

Comment: Ah; this clarifies the point you're making. I suggest you open a new question, investigating the less and more punctive senses of 'commitment' and the availability of a to-infinitive complement with each, and spelling out the question. / While 'single-minded' _does_ work better with a durative meaning of 'commitment' (the non-count sense), I'd say the to-infinitive is not precluded here. There are a reasonable number of hits on Google for 'single-minded promise'.

Answer (score 0):

We are commited to "something" generally,which normally is a noun or nominal phrase, but when the goal is to show that we are commited to an action, we use a verb+ing to have the function of a noun, therefore the sentens makes sens.